# what is the difference between? (polymorphism)

Tags: java

What is the difference between

```
List<String> lst = new LinkedList<>();
```

and

```
LinkedList<String> lst = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference other than convenience - in the first case you can change `LinkedList` to other `List` implementation (such as `ArrayList`), if you find that it works better in your application, for example, without the need to change any other code.